# Home Sharing doesn't work when using WPA2

Tags: appletv, home-sharing

I'm having problems using Home Sharing with WPA2 personal. With WEP or no password, it's fine.

Here's my setup:

Late 2010 27" iMac used for wireless Internet Sharing, running Mavericks. Apple TV 2 with the latest version running.

The Apple TV is seeing the wifi from the iMac, as I can see purchased films and music. It's just not seeing Home Sharing, even though it's all switched on in iTunes. My iPhone 5 and iPad can't see it either. But when I switch to the less secure WEP or no password, the share option appears on both iOS devices.

All suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Welcome to AskDifferent, not sure what your issue is. I have almost an identical set up which works but my home sharing is from OS X 10.7.5.  I have a 10.9 box and could test it but it's a server and I don't want to stuff around with it - good luck.